# How to call a future function from a different class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two classes `MainScreen` and `SearchScreen` which uses nested function with a boolean value
For example, here in `MainScreen`, I have a function  `showMap`, its return value is obtained from `SearchScreen`

```
Future showMap(bool checkValue) async {
        try {
            //do something
        }
        //somewhere in the widgets 
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            super.build(context);
            //
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                    await Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SearchScreen(
                                showMapFunction: showMap)));)
            }
        }
```

NoW in my `SearchScreen` I have

```
class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    final Function showMapFunction;
  

    const SearchScreen({
        this.showMapFunction
    }); //,this.String});

    @override
    _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}
///
@override
@mustCallSuper
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GestureDetector(
        onTap: () async {
            Navigator.pop(
                //send back data
                // context,
                widget.showMapFunction(true));

        },
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
}
```

This works fine, when I navigate back to `MainScreen` the function `showMap` is called, Is there any other way to do this perhaps with provider package or sth? This causes a lot of rebuilds to my widget tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to await the result of the `navigator`, like the one used in the Flutter [Cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/returning-data).

```
  void _navigateToSearch(BuildContext context) async {
 
    final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => SearchScreen())),
    );
  }
```

And then, when you pop the `Search Screen`, do the following

```
 GestureDetector(
  onTap: () async => Navigator.pop(true),
  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
),
```

I also suggest using WillPopScope.